# SQLite query fails without error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have a function that finds an `oid` from a field in a table. According to the docs, the `oid` field is automatically created and auto incremented. Sounds great.

```
def teddy_bear_id_by_url(url)
  query = "select oid from teddy_bears where url = \"#{url}\""
  res = $db.execute(query)
  return res
end
```

Unfortunately this code returns a `[]` (empty array), when running the query in the sqlite shell gives a 'good' value (e.g. `4`).

```
def teddy_bear_id_by_url(url)
  return $db.execute("select oid from teddy_bears where url = '?'", url)
end
```

The above doesn't work either.

I did indeed check that `url`contains what I think it does.

What might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure your `url` contains what you think it does? No leading or trailing whitespace? What happens if you leave the `where` clause out? And as an aside, you really should be using single quotes for string literals in SQL (SQLite allows double quotes but that just leads to bad habits) and you should be using placeholders instead of pretending you're a PHP programmer in 1999.

Comment: `url` does indeed contain what I think it does. I logged it, and it returns precisely what it should. No leading or trailing whitespace. I replaced it with single quotes and still no dice. Thanks for the placeholders tips, but I did indeed try with placeholders with the same results.

Comment: The placeholder version would be `$db.execute("select oid from teddy_bears where url = ?", url)` (i.e. no quotes around the placeholder).

Comment: I need the quotes, unfortunately, since `url` has or could have spaces. The one with which I'm testing has spaces.

Comment: The placeholder will only be recognized without the quotes, using a placeholder takes care of all the quoting and escaping issues for you (which is the big reason to use them).

Comment: Ah, let me take a look and see if it works

Comment: Ooh, it does! Thank you very much. Answer, and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably something funny going on in your `url` that, combined with your string interpolation, is messing up your SQL. Your best bet is to use placeholders with your [`execute`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/SQLite3/Database#execute-instance_method) call:

```
$db.execute("select oid from teddy_bears where url = ?", url)
```

Comment: Awesome answer, but unfortunately one more problem: the results are coming back blank (still). I queried with: ` res = $db.execute("select oid from teddy_bears where url = ?", url)` and checked with ` $log.debug res.inspect`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Have you tried just `$db.execute("select oid from teddy_bears")` or with another `url`? You say that the URL has spaces in it, have they been encoded as `%20` or `+` in your `url` variable in Ruby or the SQLite database?